# AS3/Air Shift focus from one text field to the next in ios

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, focus, textfield

I am using Flash Pro cs6, AS3, Air3.8.. And I am using textfield for input. I am trying to make it so when the user presses "Done" it shifts to the next field. I am finding conflicting information about this on all the forums, including this one. I did search but never found a fix..
I am definitely receiving the events, and I tried adding a line that identifies the keycode, which has confirmed it is receiving keycode 13. I actually made it put the keycode into the field I want the focus to shift to successfully.. It just refuses to put focus on that field..

The code I am using is stated in the docs that it will not work in iOS.. BUT it DOES work further along on the same page of script, as well as on two other ones... I have:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyhandler);


function keyhandler(event:KeyboardEvent){
if(event.charCode == 13)
{
stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyhandler);
stage.focus = null;
stage.focus = nextTextField;
}
}
```

I tried that while adding the listener to the text field first, then changed it to the stage, neither work.. I tried "requestsSoftKeyboard" and several other ways I have seen posted that supposedly work in iOS, but they didn't work.. There are other functions that use the same stage.focus to null, followed by stage.focus to MyTextField and they work, but they are initiated by pressing a button on the stage, NOT a button on the soft keyboard. The code there that works is just a standard if statement:

```
if (TextField == "")
{
stage.focus=null;
stage.focus=TextField;
}else if (NextTextField == "")
{
stage.focus = null;
stage.focus = NextTextField;
}else if (TextFieldAfterThat == "")
{
stage.focus = null;
stage.focus = TextFieldAfterThat;
}
```

That continues through all fields and always goes to the right one with the soft keyboard open, cursor blinking, and ready to type.. every time. I know the listeners are received from the soft keyboard "Done" because a function to capitalize the words works, and when I added code to confirm the keycode it worked. I also have found access to that value using "charcode" AND "keycode".. I do not know what the difference is, but both returned 13 and neither worked for me..
There is another place I use the same code to make a TextField active and set the focus after the user presses a radio button, and those all work every time.

I am not sure what the difference is coming from pressing "Done" vs. pressing an object on the stage, but it refuses to set the focus with the done button.
Anyone have any ideas or made this work before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had success assingning focus to a `StageText` in iOS like this:

```
stageText.assignFocus();
```

`StageText` offers many advantages over `TextField` because it shows a native text input. The only disadvantage I know is that you can't use custom fonts.

Here's the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StageText.html), and a [tutorial](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/09/native-text-input-with-stagetext.html).

I haven't experimented with the "Done" key, but I did what you are trying to achieve with "Enter" key and it worked. Also take note that in iOS the "Done" key is meant to hide the keyboard, so that could be why you are having these problems..

Comment: Yes.. I have seen stageText.. I wrote the app for Android originally and am now trying to do iOS. I was hoping not to have to rewrite all the text fields since there are so many. The "Done" key triggers the same "13" value as it does when it says "Enter"... I guess I may end up having to switch them all over to stageText, but if anyone has any other suggestions I would love to hear.

Comment: If you go with the `StageText` route, the easiest way would be to write your own wrapper, and simply change the class of your classic textfields to `StageTextWrapper`. Yes you'd have to write wrapper with getter/setters, but  you could keep your previous code almost intact.

Comment: That is true.. I will have to look into that for a bit... Thank you. Have you ever played with Christians NativeText wrapper? I am trying to decide if it will save time to use that or if I should just go to writing my own...

Comment: I didn't use Christian's (I wrote my own) but I saw the code on Github. If it doesn't fit your purposes it should at least be a good place to start. It seems the major `TextField` properties are already taken care of with getter/setters.

Comment: If you find my answer helpful (even if it's not correct) you could at least upvote it ;)

Comment: I cant... It says I must have at least 15 reputation before I can.. :-(

Answer (score 0):

With component FPTextField you can listen to the event click DONE. In this video, compared StageText and FPTextField: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKYaoLtEmCU

Use ane library FPNativeUI: http://flashpress.ru/blog/ane/native-ui/?lang=en